# python3 quicksort list index out of range

Tags: python, debugging, traceback

Hi I am new to Python and when I implemented the following code for the quick-sort algorithm I got a traceback: "IndexError: list index out of range".

Can anybody help me, please. I have been struggled for the whole night!

Thanks!

```
def quicksort(array,l,r):
    n = len(array)
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return array
    else:
        p = array[l]
        i = l + 1
        for j in range(l+1, r):
            if array[j] < p:
                array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
                i = i + 1
        array[l], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[l]
        array[l:i-1] = quicksort(array[l:i-1],l,i-1)
        array[i:r] = quicksort(array[i:r],i,r)
        return array

testarray = [1,3,4,5,2]
sortedarray = quicksort(testarray,0,5)
```

Comment: I changed "array[i:r] = quicksort(array[i:r],i,r)" to "array[i:r] = quicksort(array[i:r],l,r-i)", and the code works. For those who may encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the error but your sorting logic is wrong, I think

```
def quicksort(array,l,r):
    n = len(array)
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return array
    else:
        p = array[l]
        i = l + 1
        for j in range(1, r-1):  # r is length of array; so range should be one less
            if array[j] < p:
                array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
                i = i + 1
        array[l], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[l]
        array[l:i-1] = quicksort(array[l:i-1],l,i-1)
        array[i:r] = quicksort(array[i:r],i,r)
        return array

testarray = [1,3,4,5,2]
sortedarray = quicksort(testarray,0,5) 

print(sortedarray)
```

Output

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thx! I find that "array[i:r] = quicksort(array[i:r],i,r)" indicates that every subarray has a length of r, which is wrong in logic!